# what is mean of invariant?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, differential-geometry, definition, mapping-class-group

in the [A Primer on Mapping Class Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691147949) we have :

Geometric intersection number is a useful **invariant** but, as
we will see, it is more difficult to compute than the algebraic intersection
number.

> what is mean of **invariant** ?  why this is **useful**  ?

is this mean homeomorphisms preserve geometric intersection number? or Geometric intersection number is  invariant under homeomorphisms ? ( also algebraic intersection
number invariant under homeomorphisms orientation preserving.
) let $h$ be a homeomorphism then $i(h(a),h(b))=i(a,b) $ ?

i know in mathematics, an invariant is a property of a mathematical object (or a class of mathematical objects) which remains unchanged after operations or transformations of a certain type are applied to the objects.but for Geometric intersection number where is this  invariant ?

Comment: An "invariant" is something that is the same for any of a number of ways to define it, like for a finite dimensional vector space, the dimension is the number of vectors in any basis of the given vector space. It comes out the same for different bases of that vector space.

Comment: This question is best suited for [https://ell.stackexchange.com] (English language learners stack)

Comment: What is your def. of geometric intersection number? Are you referring to, the intersection number of two oriented submanifolds $S_1,S_2$ in an oriented manifold $X$?
In that case,  it might be intended as an invariant of the isotopy class of the embedding of the $S_i$, i.e. if you change the embedding of $S_i$ with another one isotopic to it the result does not change.

Answer (score 2):

in [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=KPoEtBwBEA0C&pg=PA21&dq=Geometric%20intersection%20number%20is%20invariant&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz1cac9tz3AhX-wQIHHU5IAVAQ6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=Geometric%20intersection%20number%20is%20invariant&f=false) (Subgroups of Teichmuller Modular Groups
By Nikolai V. Ivanov page 21) we have :

geometric intersection number of circles, it follows that it is **invariant under the action of the modular group**: $$i(h(a),h(b))=i(a,b) $$ for $h \in  Mod(S)$